# golang pgconnection pool - how to test if the pool was initialized or empty

Tags: go

I am not fully familiar with golang patterns / best practices with respect to database connections.  I am trying to implement a simple web service in go, using jackc/pgx connection pool.

In a file (let us call it users.go, which is a web service with user registration methods), I am having a connection pool object at the module level.  Every time a request lands on the app, I want to test if the connection pool was initialized,if yes return the pool, else initialize the pool and return it.

I am trying to write code as below..

```golang
var pool Pool


// the request handler fn
func registerUser (c *gin.Context) {

  // get connection pool and insert into db.
  pool, err = getConnPool()

  ...
} 

// the getConnPool function
func getConnPool () {
  // How to test if the pool was not initialized???
  if pool == nil {
   // initialize
   pool, err := pgxpool.Connect(context.Background(), os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
   return pool, err
  }
  return pool, nil
}
```

How to test the pool variable if it is connected / not nil etc?

I am not sure, if this is the correct approach in go, while I have used this kind of lazy initialization in NodeJS frequently.  Should I initialize the pool in the main file, or is there an alternative like above?

Comment: In general you should initialize the pool once at program startup. To test whether or not the connection was successful you should check the error and [ping](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4@v4.16.1/pgxpool#Conn.Ping) the db. The lazy-loading in this case seem to me completely unnecessary, besides your implementation is not safe for concurrency.

Comment: what you are trying to do is to test the framework and not your own code, the libraries are mostly battle-tested and you can assume that they will work as expected. I agree with @mkopriva that a simple `ping` will be enough to make sure all the things are initialised properly